# How to get page-source of an element in mobile native app by selenium script?

Tags: selenium, automation, appium

I'm using Appium for automation of mobile application and I want is just the pagesource of an element of a native app. I have googled a lot and found that its possible for webpages but did not get any solution for mobile's native app.
like below examples.

```
elem.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

OR

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
String contents = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is getPageSource() method:

```
driver.getPageSource();
```

**Update**

To get source code of specific element (including element's tag):

```
element.getAttribute('outerHTML')
```

Comment: I don't want page source of entire page, I just want the page source of a specific element. Something like
<h1 name="title">Title</h1>

Comment: @pr4bh4sh, `element.getAttribute('innerHTML')`?

Comment: Probably you need this: `element.getAttribute('innerHTML')`

Comment: for iOS it doesn't work. "UIAElements don't have the attribute 'outerHTML'" -  that's what Appium says

Comment: @kiedysktos, try to change context from native to web.

Comment: For CodeceptJS: await I.grabSource()

Comment: this doesn't work with Python Appium 2.7.1 as of 2022/11/17. The error I get is: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.NoSuchAttributeException: 'outerHTML' attribute is unknown for the element. Only the following attributes are supported: [checkable, checked, {class,className}, clickable, {content-desc,contentDescription}, enabled, focusable, focused, {long-clickable,longClickable}, package, password, {resource-id,resourceId}, scrollable, selection-start, selection-end, selected, {text,name}, bounds, displayed, contentSize]